# Fancybox slides going to bottom of page in IE8, under background

Tags: internet-explorer-8, fancybox, z-index

I'm using Fancybox v.2 (with jquery 1.7.1) - it works beautifully in chrome, but in IE8 the whole thing appears at the bottom of the page, with the greyed background on top.

Is it a z-index thing?  I don't see anything wrong with the original code, and the Fancybox website displays fine in IE8....

Comment: could you share a link with the issue? it seems to be a very specific issue. Have checked you have a proper `DOCTYPE` ?

Answer (score 1):

I too got the same problem, the popup was displaying at the bottom of the page. I solved by adding the doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: This fixed Fancybox for me, but it broke the rest of my page :(